# find passphrase on encrypted ssh private key

Tags: ssh, password-cracking, passphrase

I have an openssh encrypted private key. I don't remember the pass-phrase. I may be able to suggest words or patterns that may be in the phrase.

I am looking for software that will help me recover the key.

I am thinking of a tool that can generate a stream of pass-phrases, based on my hints, a dictionary and some randomness. Then piping this into something like `expect` and `ssh-add`.

Can someone tell me what tools are available.

---

I am running Debian Gnu+Linux.

ps. next I will look at a way to not forget my pass-phrase, and a more secure encryption.

Comment: Try [this](http://leidecker.info/projects/phrasendrescher.shtml) - it looks old and not maintained anymore, but it may still work.

Answer (score 4):

[John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2011/07/03/2) supports cracking SSH private key passphrases. If you provide a dictionary it will be even faster. Alternatively, you can also use [Phrasendrescher](http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/phrasendrescher).